# Drag&Drop NSURL without "file://"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing my drag&drop method. I need that when user drags something on my app window I can get that file URL. `NSURL` needs to be converted to `char`. Thats OK. But how to remove `file://` from url? My current code:

```
pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
NSString *url = [[NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pboard] absoluteString];
input_imageN = strdup([url UTF8String]);
```

its OK, but it gives url with `file://` prefix. I tried using

```
NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pboard] isFileURL];
NSString *url = [fileUrl absoluteString];
NSLog(@"url: %@", [NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pboard]);
input_imageN = strdup([url UTF8String]);
```

but it says that

```
Cannot initialize a variable of type 'NSURL *' with an rvalue of type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char')
```

at

```
NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pboard] isFileURL];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
url = [url stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"file://" withString:@""];
```

Comment: try this [self. url path];

Answer (score 16):

To go from a file URL to the path as a C string in the appropriate representation for the filesystem, you'd do:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLFromPasteboard: pboard];
NSString *filePath = [fileURL path];
char *filesystemRepresentation = [filePath filesystemRepresentation];
```

This avoids assumptions that stripping off the scheme leaves you with just the path, or that the filesystem is definitely happy accepting UTF8-encoded paths.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Using `path` is a way cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

@user23743's answer is correct. Since iOS 7 though `NSURL` has its own `filestSystemRepresentation` method.

In Swift:

```
if let fileURL = NSURL(fromPasteboard: pboard) {
    let representation = fileURL.fileSystemRepresentation
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if let fileURL = NSURL(from: pboard)?.filePathURL {
}
```

has been most effective for me.